# Run kie server source code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, drools, kie-server

I want to extend the Drools Kie-server with some new functionalities. I have downloaded 'kie-server-parent' source code from Git, and imported it as existing maven project in eclipse. I have also configured my eclipse with Tomcat server.

Can anyone please provide me guidelines on how can I execute this source code in this eclipse environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To run Kie server on Tomcat you need to build the application. You can do it by executing maven command `mvn clean install` in kie-server-parent folder.

After successful build you can find deployable war file in folder kie-server-parent/kie-server-wars/kie-server/target. Deploy this file on Tomcat, instructions are [in Drools documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e24240). For deploying on Tomcat use war file with webc classifier.